# Scoping a listener as session in Spring 3 throws exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How can i scope a listener with the session scope? I need this listener be executed for each user connected, but when i try to scope it, throws the next exception

Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I included this in my web.xml, but nothing

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is the listener, if required

```
public class ReauthenticatingEventsPostProcessor implements    ApplicationListener<ReauthenticatingUseronRoleChangeEvent> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    UserDAO userDao;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ReauthenticatingUseronRoleChangeEvent e) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>  (auth.getAuthorities());
        Role r = new Role();
        r.setRole(e.getRoleType());
        authorities.add(r);
        Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the filter do that makes you think it is required for it to be session scoped?

Comment: You cannot scape the listener to session scope.  instead, you will need to retrieve the session in the listener.

Comment: the idea is accessing to each SecurityContextHolder

Comment: The `SecurityContextHolder` is thread bound - therefore it is safe to access it the way you do it.